# After Ubuntu OS update, I'm getting â in the terminal

Tags: ubuntu

I've update my Ubuntu to the latest release:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```

Now I get the annoying **â** in the place of, I'm guessing, the **'**. E.g.:

```
removed âsomefile.txtâ
```

It seems to be a UTF or ISO coding?
Where do I check for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/366895/getting-%C3%82-and-%C3%A2-characters-in-linux-putty-console), it seems that my putty was set to ISO-8859-1:1998(Latin-1, West Europe). I changed it to UTF-8 and it works fine.

(Don't know how I missed it before)